# Python TypeError "list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python, mapreduce

trying to convert the json to csv, but why doesn't this work?
The following error appears:

> x['Emotions']['Confidence'][0], TypeError: list indices must be
>   integers, not str

```
for person in output_json["Record"]:
    csv_data = person["Person"]
    for x in csv_data:
        f = csv.writer(open('/tmp/test.csv', 'wb+'))
        f.writerow(["FrameNumber", "FrameTimePosition", "Gender", "Emotions_Type1", "Emotions_Confidence1",
                    "Emotions_Type2", "Emotions_Confidence2", "Emotions_Type3", "Emotions_Confidence3",
                    "AgeRange_High", "AgeRange_low"])
        print(x['FrameNumber'])
        print(x['FrameTimePosition'])
        print(x['Gender']['Value'])

        f.writerow([x['FrameNumber'],
                    x['FrameTimePosition'],
                    x['Gender']['Value'],
                    x['Emotions']['Confidence'][0],
                    x['Emotions']['Type'][0],
                    x['Emotions']['Confidence'][1],
                    x['Emotions']['Type'][1],
                    x['Emotions']['Confidence'][2],
                    x['Emotions']['Type'][2],
                    x['AgeRange']['High'],
                    x['AgeRange']['Low']])
```

The following Json, I already follow the output format, but I don't know why it's not working

```
 {
        "Record": [
            {
                "Person": [
                    {
                        "FrameNumber": 1, 
                        "FrameTimePosition": "0:00:01", 
                        "Gender": {
                            "Confidence": 99.86161041259766, 
                            "Value": "Male"
                        }, 
                        "Emotions": [
                            {
                                "Confidence": 83.7345199584961, 
                                "Type": "HAPPY"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "Confidence": 3.3157408237457275, 
                                "Type": "CONFUSED"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "Confidence": 1.5936851501464844, 
                                "Type": "CALM"
                            }
                        ],
                        ...
                    }
                ],
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Emotions is presumably a list. You should show the actual data.

Comment: thanks for reminding me, i already updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're trying to get a list value by it's key. 
You're probably are thinking is a dictionary (similar to an object {} in JSON) when it's a list (array[], in JSON).

I suggest you to check the types in your JSON, specially for the keys that appears in the error

```
x['Emotions']['Confidence'][0]
```

Your `x['Emotions']` probably is a array an not a object in your base JSON.

**Edit after the JSON**

`x['Emotions']` is an array (list in python), what I think you probably want wiith this line is to get the values with key `'Confidence'`, so you gonna need to invert the order, like this:

```
x['Emotions'][0]['Confidence']
```

Here you getting the first element of the list with the key `'Emotions'`, 
getting a dict like that:

```
{
    "Confidence": 83.7345199584961, 
    "Type": "HAPPY"
}
```

and, from this element, the `'Confidence'` property.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply, I updated the Json format, but I still don't understand what's happening...